# How to adjust the TextField to be on the same horizontal alignment as the search icon?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

The text in TextField seems to be aligned to the bottom of the box instead of being aligned horizontally as the search icon. How do i fix this part of the UI?

Here's the code in flutter/dart:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(
    SafeArea(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        // darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),        
        home: Scaffold(          
          appBar: AppBar(  
            centerTitle: false,
            title: const Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
              child: Text('Logo',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFFD2A829), 
                        fontSize: 30,
                        // shadows: [Shadow(color: Colors.black,
                        //           offset: Offset(-5, -5,),
                        //           blurRadius: 300)]
                                  ),),            
            ),
            backgroundColor:const  Color(0xFFf8dab7),
            actions: const [Icon(Icons.menu, 
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 30 ,),
                     SizedBox(width: 38)],
            toolbarHeight: 50,
            elevation: 0,            
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFf8dab7),


          body:
             Column(
              children: [
               
                const SizedBox(height: 50,), // Spacing between logo and search bar.
                
                Row(children: [
                 const SizedBox(width: 10,),// Space next to magnifier

                 Container( // Search box                  
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  width: 250,
                  height: 35,                   
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                    )]
                     ),                   
                   child: TextField(
                     textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                     textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                     inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                     decoration: InputDecoration(
                       border: InputBorder.none,
                       hintText: 'Tracking ID (Digits only)',
                       icon: Icon(Icons.search),),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,),                            
                   ),
                  ),
```

I tried to look into the properties of TextField, but i don't see anything specific to fixing the height or alignment of the TextField based on the background.

Comment: Please format your code in your post properly. Also i dont see any textfield or icon in your code. Please provide the full code so we can see whats going on

Comment: please add more detail,. your code only show the container.

Comment: Sorry for missing out the TextField part earlier. I've added the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `contentPadding` in the `InputDecoration` of the `TextField` like below:

```
decoration: const InputDecoration(
   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
   border: InputBorder.none,
   hintText: 'Tracking ID (Digits only)',
   icon: Icon(Icons.search),
),
```